# Intercepting Outlook category assignment events?

Tags: events, outlook, variable-assignment, categories

Note this is not a duplicate of [this similar but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832379/is-it-possible-to-intercept-outlook-categories-events)!

My question is not how to intercept Category create / rename / delete events, but how to intercept when a user **assigns a category to an item** (contact, meeting etc). I am just starting to explore the Outlook object model, and I'm struggling to 'get' how it works. Any assistance in the right direction would be fantastic!

I realise I'm not providing much detail and this seems like a 'please do it for me' type question, but I really only need a brief idea of if this is possible, unfortunatley I don't have much time to research. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need and Inspector wrapper and and Explorer wrapper to get all the places that you can change the category (as you can right click in the explorer view).

But they catagory assignment should fire the Item PropertyChange event.
In the explorer you will have to track the selected items and wire up the PropertyChange  event for each item in the selection.

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution. Not anything I have actually tried, yet.

- [OlkCategoryEvents_Event.Change Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olkcategoryevents_event.change%28v=office.12%29.aspx)  - `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` - Occurs when a category selection has changed. Namespace: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`
- Assembly: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` (in `microsoft.office.interop.outlook.dll`), using 
  event `OlkCategoryEvents_ChangeEventHandler` Change