# Capturing the assigned category to email in excel sheet (real time) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My goal is to capture to an excel sheet what category each email is assigned.

I want to capture this information in real time as once categorized the emails are then moved to different folders.

So I am running the below code in "ThisOutlookSession" to save the Subject & the Body of the received emails (I also sometimes capture the received date/time, etc...):

```
Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
      Set olApp = Outlook.Application
      Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item


    Dim XLApp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim XlWK As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    ' New Excel.Application
    Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     On Error Resume Next
   Set wb = XLApp.Workbooks.Open _
 ("C:\Users\Name\Downloads\Test.xlsx")
 XLApp.Visible = True
 wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Msg.Subject
 wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value = Msg.Body
    On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox Msg.Subject
    MsgBox Msg.Body

  End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

My goal is to capture once the email is categorized (i.e. once a category is assigned to an email). I think the ItemChange event will be the way to go, but haven't had any luck getting it to work so far.

Any advise on how to go about changing my code to capture the email's body & subject once the category is assigned will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Not much there but see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312050/intercepting-outlook-category-assignment-events) thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right avenue - the [ItemChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866(v=office.15).aspx) is a way to go. For example:

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items  

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
    Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items  
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)  
    Dim prompt As String    
    prompt = Item.Categories 
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
       Item.Display  
    End If         
End Sub
```

Also you may consider handling the [PropertyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868239(v=office.15).aspx) event of Outlook items.